# Fourthly nested quoting in JSP

Tags: html, jsp, nested, liferay, quoting

How can I make Tomcat swallow this line?? I tried all quoting combinations!

```
 <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name="howstheweather" 
   value="<liferay-ui:message key='<%=("Sun").equals(timeBean.today())?"sunny-day-msg":"take-umbrella-msg"%>'/>"
 />
```

Asking if there is any solution, not assessing changing to EL and JSLT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use jsp-tag in values of other jsp-tag. But the `<liferay-ui:search-container-column-text .../>`-Tag has a `translate` attribute. Hier the solution for you:

```
<liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name="howstheweather" 
  value='<%=("Sun").equals(timeBean.today())?"sunny-day-msg":"take-umbrella-msg"%>'
  translate='true'
/>
```